# Copy items using progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms

I am copying large files from one place to another.
It is taking a long time so I decided to use a progress bar.

I am following this [example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar).

The `copyItems()` function iterates through the list items and copies the items from another place. It in turn calls a  function CopyListItem which copies one item .

I  need to tie the backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i) to the total no of items i.e. itemcoll.

I do not want to use `thread.sleep()` .

The progress bar needs to show the actual time required to copy the file from one place to another.

The Progress bar needs to **progress when only** when one file is copied. 
IT **needs to complete** when all the  files are copied

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Start the BackgroundWorker.
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= itemscoll.count; i++)
            {
                // Wait 100 milliseconds.
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                // Report progress.
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
            }
        }
        private void CopyListItem(SPListItem sourceItem, string destinationListName, string destServerURL)
        {
            // copy items
        }
        private void copyitems()
        {
            try
            {
                int createdYear = 0;
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
                foreach (SPListItem sourceItem in itemscoll)
                {
                    if (Helper.year == createdYear)
                    {
                        CopyListItem(sourceItem, Helper.destinationListName,Helper.destServerURL);
                        DeleteItem(CompRefNo);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch()
            {}
        }
        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Change the value of the ProgressBar to the BackgroundWorker progress.
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            // Set the text.
            this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying _you are having problems reporting progress_ or that _"I do not want to use thread.sleep()"_

Comment: You need to show a time instead of a progress I guess, something like a Estimated time ...

Comment: The thread.sleep function delays the time for each progress item by a specific time delay. I don't know how long the copyListItem function would take to finish . The progressbar is not  linked to the no of items to copy.

Comment: I would rephrase the first two sentences.

"I am copying large files from one place to another. It is taking a long time so I decided to use a progress bar" -> Implies that using a progress bar would lower copy time.

Comment: If I get you right: You want to increase the progressbar every time an item was copied and the maximum-value of the progressbar should be the total amount of items, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do your copy-action in the DoWork-Event of the `BackgroundWorker`. So when you call the `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()` you'll have to pass an object to it containing all the needed informations. This could be something like:

```
internal class WorkerItem
{
    public WorkerItem(List<SPListItem> spListItems, string destinationListName, string destinationServerURL)
    {
        SPListItems = new List<SPListItem>(spListItems);
        DestinationListName = destinationListName;
        DestinationServerURL = destinationServerURL;
    }

    public List<SPListItem> SPListItems { get; private set; }
    public string DestinationListName { get; private set; }
    public string DestinationServerURL { get; private set; }
}
```

The call of RunWorkerAsync can look something like:

`backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(new WorkerItem(...));`

In your DoWork-Handler you than have to get this object from the `e.Argument` and cast it to `WorkerItem`. Than you can work with it like:

```
private void BackgroundWorker1OnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    WorkerItem workerItem = (WorkerItem)e.Argument;

    for (int i = 0; i < workerItem.SPListItems.Count(); i++)
    {
        // CopyListItem is doing the copy for one item.
        CopyListItem(workerItem.SPListItems[i], workerItem.DestinationListName, workerItem.DestinationServerURL);
        ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress(i + 1);
    }
}
```

The ProgressChanged-Handler only increments the value of the `ProgressBar`:

```
private void BackgroundWorker1OnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

If you want to have more informations in the ProgressChanged-Handler you can pass an additional object as UserState. This you can get by `object additional = e.UserState;`

Right before you call `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(new WorkerItem(...))` you should set the Maximum of progressBar1 to the amount of SPListItems like:

```
progressBar1.Maximum = itemscoll.Count;
```

Your `BackgroundWorker` only reports it's progress to you if you set.

```
backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

If you want to be informed when the `BackgroundWorker` is finished you can get the RunWorkerCompleted-Event.

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker1OnRunWorkerCompleted;
```